# Add new form input fields on option select basis using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, logic

I have an html form where on the input field selection from a drop down i want to add some html input fields. I am using `append()` but it actually just appends to the div let say i have 2 options 1,2 on selecting 1 some input fields are added to the form but on selecting 2 input fields for option 1 remains the same. What another method i can use instead off append ? I am really missing something very basic, googled a lot but not helping in this case.

```
jQuery('#category').change(function() {
   if( $(this).val() == 1 ) {
      // input fields to add for 1
   }
   if( $(this).val() == 4 ) {
     // input fields to add for 4
   }
});
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. Just select the correct parent element if the `DIV` you talked about isn't the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create all the input fields initially in the form and do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#inputfield1").hide();
    $("#inputfield2").hide();
});

jQuery('#category').change(function() {
   if( $(this).val() == 1 ) {
      $("#inputfield1").show();
      $("#inputfield2").hide();
   }
   if( $(this).val() == 4 ) {
      $("#inputfield2").show();
      $("#inputfield1").hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the Input field at the same position. And set its css `display:none;` and change the property to `display:block;`  on drop down change value.